# Any Way To Swap Some File Or Some %

Tags: 11.10, swap

is there any way to do some  % swap

example i want to swap 2 % of my data to swap

OR

is there any way i can swap some program

example i want to swap firefox , or any program

Comment: The swap space is managed by the kernel, and I don't know of any utility to do what you ask. Also, the motivation for your question are not clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the kernel's swappiness parameter (which doesn't really do what you're wanting), but that's about all you can do. Otherwise, the kernel just does what it deems best.

And, if you swap Firefox out entirely, you'd probably save time by just exiting it than waiting ages for swap.